# How to update quantity in session array on the go?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I want to capture value keyed in textbox for quantity in the shopping cart while they type. I used jquery's key up for this.Then I want to save the new value in the session for quantity. I'm getting the value but unable to save it. It returns null after refreshing the page.

Html

```
<input type="text" size="4" class="qty" value="<?php echo $v['quantity'];?>" id="<?php echo $k;?>"/>
```

Ajax

```
$("input[class=qty]").keyup(function()
     {
        var data;
         var newVal = $(this).val();

         var id = this.id;
         console.log(id+" "+newVal);
         $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "text",
              url: "updateCart.php?id="+id+"&&value"+newVal, //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
              data: data,
              success: function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                 newVal=data;
              }
            });

     });
```

updateCart.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_GET['id'];//say 2
$new_value =$_GET['value'];//say 16
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k=>$v)
{

    $k;
    $v["id"];
    $v["quantity"];
    if($id == $k)
    {
        //assign new value to the quantity
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']=$new_value;
        //print_r($_SESSION['cart'][1]['quantity']);
    }

}
//echo json_encode($new_value);
//var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);
```

this can display session['cart'] with updated value if I test in
this page ..but when passed to originated page via ajax, returns null.

```
echo $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity'];
?>
```

Comment: please show code that you use to retrieve it in the other page where it returns null. By the way $id is set on updateCart.php so if you go ` echo $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity'];` it doesn't know what $id is. You need to call it by actual $id value, which is whatever you have set in updateCart.php

Comment: Just a typo. You're missing the `=` after `&value`.

Comment: Just another reason why it's better to use `data: { id: id, value: newVal}` instead of creating the URL by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out the `=` between `&value` and `+ newVal`. But I recommend you let jQuery do this automatically by using the `data:` option.

```
    data = { id: id, value: newVal };
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        url: "updateCart.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            newVal=data;
        }
    });
```